# Android app POST request to Apache sending Expect 100 header

Tags: android, apache, http-headers

I've one android application which makes an POST request to one apache server. But the app sends the "Expect: 100" header, apache responds with a 417 status message, and the connection is finished and nothing is done...

I've used the mod_header, on .htaccess and pre_virtualhost_global.conf files to remove the expect header, but doesn't works.

What's the best way to do this? On server or on the app? And how fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem using the following code, where mClient is one object of DefaultHttpClient class.

```
mClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
```

If anyone has a batter solution, please share.